# Can a single atom in vacuum space have a temperature?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, atomic-physics

Say that there was a single atom alone in a vacuum without any particles for it to bounce off of; would it have a temperature?

As we all know motion is relative, however with nothing to bounce or collide with, is the atom moving?  Or if it's not moving, then is absolute zero achieved?  Or if it is moving, then will it "slow down" as it gives off thermal energy, producing thermal energy?

note that i am not talking about : particle speeds in idealized gases where the particles move freely inside a stationary container without interacting with one another, except for very brief collisions

i am talking about no collisions with anything therefore the Maxwell–Boltzmann distribution is a different thing than what im talking about therfore Can a single molecule have a temperature is a totally different question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a single molecule have a temperature?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65690/)