# Does temperature only depend on the translational kinetic energy of a molecule?

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetic-theory

SO, I think we define temperature as something related to the average translational kinetic energy of a molecule.

Is temperature dependent on the rotational and vibrational energy of the molecules.
If so, why??

Comment: I think this is a different question than https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/65690/can-a-single-molecule-have-a-temperature. This question is not asking if it is possible to define the temperature of a single molecule. On the basis of the text, I understand that the question is how the temperature (of a macroscopic system) is related to the kinetic energy of a molecule. I'll vote for reopening.